# Using the remote server's aliases while connecting through a ssh connection

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, command-line, terminal

i've been trying to configure my application to send through commands via ssh. The ssh connection definitely works okay but I want to be able to send through '1' on the command line and this to open a file on the remote server. This alias works correctly on the remote machine but it won't work when the '1' command is given through ssh. I've read around and apparently this is happening due to the shell being non-interactive. However, due to the constraints of my application I can't alter the ssh launch script easily. I'm instead looking for a way to alter the remote machine's ~bashrc file to allow the local machine to access the aliases on it. I've tried adding

```
if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
  shopt -s expand_aliases

fi
```

To the ~bashrc file but it doesn't work.Any help would be a godsend!

Comment: So what do you exactly do? `ssh <MACHIN> 1`?

Comment: Yeph that was my command line setup.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out why this was not working, within my code i had connect to ssh and then immediately disconnect from ssh channel. The process was being run but then immediately shut down before it had time to execute.